# Lambda File Write to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, lambda

For the past six months I have been downloading the NASA APOD and saving to an S3 bucket using a Lambda function. Up until 12/23/2016 all was working as expected. Now when I check my bucket, the images are there but size 0 bytes. I have included my code below. Does anyone know if there has been a change? Thanks!

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

// Incoming Handler
// <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
    exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
        GetAPOD();
    };
// <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>

// Functions
// <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
    function GetAPOD() {
        var nasa_api_key = 'MY KEY GOES HERE'
        ,   nasa_api_path = '/planetary/apod?api_key=' + nasa_api_key;

        var options = {
            host: 'api.nasa.gov',
            port: 443,
            path: nasa_api_path,
            method: 'GET'
        };

        // Connect to the NASA API and get the APOD.
        var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
            console.log('Open connection to NASA.');
            res.setEncoding('utf-8');

            var responseString = '';
            res.on('data', function (data) {
                responseString = data;
            });

            res.on('end', function () {
                console.log('API Response: ' + responseString);

                var responseObject = JSON.parse(responseString)
                ,   image_date = responseObject['date']
                ,   image_url = responseObject['url']
                ,   image_hdurl = responseObject['hdurl']
                ,   media_type = responseObject['media_type'];

                if (media_type == 'image') {
                    var image_name = image_date + '.jpg';

                    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
                    var s3Bucket = new AWS.S3( { params: {Bucket: 'nasa-apod'} } );

                    // Check to see if the image already exists in the S3 bucket.
                    // If not we will upload the image to S3.
                    var head_data = {Key: image_name};
                    s3Bucket.headObject(head_data, function(err, output_head_data) {
                        if (output_head_data) {
                            console.log("Image exists on S3.");
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("Image does not exists on S3.");
                            // Image has not been uploaded to S3, open a stream and download the image to the /tmp folder.

                            var file = fs.createWriteStream("/tmp/" + image_name);
                            var request = http.get(image_url, function(response) {
                                console.log("Opening file stream.");

                                // Pipe the data into the file stream and save to disk.
                                response.pipe(file);

                                response.on('end', function () {
                                    // File is written to disk, we are going to check that it exists. 
                                    var fileName = "/tmp/" + image_name;
                                    fs.exists(fileName, function(exists) {
                                        if (exists) {
                                            console.log("File exits in /tmp folder.");

                                            // Get the stats for the image, will need this for the ContentLength
                                            fs.stat(fileName, function(error, stats) {
                                                if (error) {
                                                    console.log("Stat Error: " + error);
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                    console.log("Opening file stream.");
                                                    var image_stream = fs.createReadStream(fileName);

                                                    // Begin the upload process to S3.
                                                    var param_data = {Key: image_name, Body: image_stream, ContentType: "image/jpeg", ContentLength: stats.size, ACL: "public-read"};
                                                    s3Bucket.putObject(param_data, function(err, output_data) {
                                                        if (err) {
                                                            console.log('Error uploading data to S3: ' + err); 
                                                        }
                                                        else {
                                                            console.log('Image successfully uploaded.');
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            console.log('File does not exist in the /tmp folder.');
                                        }
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Media Type: " + media_type);
                }
            });
        });

        req.on('error', function (e) {
            console.error('HTTP error: ' + e.message);
        });

        req.end();
    }
// <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out that NASA APOD API is now using https and not http for images. I had to adjust my code to use https for the image path.